# I need a dynamic way to apply css content based on DOM innerhtml values

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I currently use react js to dynamically render search results of an api inside a `<div id="results">` tag. The domain results render like this:

```
<div id="results">yahoo.com
bracket.io
codepin.io
samplesite.net
</div>
```

I have css applied to the div itself but how do I apply "css content" based on the innerHtml inside the DOM element (for example regex based on the actual words). The purpose I ask this is because I would like to append something in the css based on the tld of the returned domain, if I get a .com site, Id like css to know somehow that inside the div element a site named .com was rendered then dynamically apply this to include the same for all others.

```
.results {

content: site .com was rendered;
content: site .net was rendered;
}
```

An so forth.

Comment: the simplest solution is to dynamically add a class to a wrapper div.

Comment: Yes, this would be in your React code, not in your CSS

Comment: Okay, how do I do that? Using what method, js? Can you be more specific

Comment: Again everyone is responding with the easiest and obvious, are there any suggestions from the JS side of how to do that best practice?

Comment: @SulaymanTouray I am not into reactjs. Basic javascript way is here : [className property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp)

Comment: @SulaymanTouray "best practice" is something that is hard to apply for a one-liner of a problem. It is typically applicable to the bigger picture.

Comment: If you could post the code part you use now to render the result, it would help to suggest a solution

Answer (score 0):

You would have something like:

```
render() {
  <div className='results'>
    { this.props.results.map ((tld) => {
      <span className=classNames({ [`results__${tld}`]: true });> 
        // list of results
      </span>
    }
  </div>
}
```

where results would be an object that has been created in an adapter after getting your data from your api.

You would then adapt it in a way that would sort it into groups based on the tld.

[JedWatson/classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) would give you the dynamic classNames